# Index html generation failed

Tags: angular, typescript, build

[image]

```
C:\Users\mypc\Documents\GitHub\my-project> ng build
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Copying assets complete.
✖ Index html generation failed.
undefined:6:349398: property missing ':'
```

I want to get a build to take my project live, but I encounter this error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.